# Can javascript calculate percentage?

Tags: jquery, percentage

We list a large library of fees. Some have a 10% (GST) tax, some have a custom #.##% tax.

The results should print as follows:

$123.45    10%     TOTAL: $135.8

$123.45    0%      TOTAL: $123.45

$123.45    7%      TOTAL: $132.10

To print these results in our CMS we use metadata values and keywords:

```
%asset_metadata_Amount%    %asset_metadata_GST%   %asset_metadata_Custom_Tax%
```

If value for '_GST' is empty, it'll print '_Custom_Tax', if they're both empty, then no calculation needs to occur.

I know IDs help the query, so:

```
<span id="row_1"><span id="abc">%asset_metadata_Amount%</span> <span id="def">%asset_metadata_GST%</span> <span id="xyz">%asset_metadata_Custom_Tax%</span> <span id="total"> # </span></span>
```

I need to provide some clarification, apologies everyone; can a function run using the keywords to perform the multiplication? ie. can the code be written as

```
total = %_Amout% * 1.%_GST%
```

Or will the '%' symbols trash the script?

Comment: Do you want to ask something, or are you just providing specs for a task that you want us to do for you?

Comment: Yes, Javascript can calculate percentage. You should try it. It's called multiplication.

Comment: @lanzz yes, sorry, last time I was polite in a post someone came along and edited the politeness out of it and stripped it to the core. I'm still learning my SO etiquette, apologies.

Comment: @user1038627: It's not about politeness, but about the actual question that you want to ask; you have described what you _want_ to do, but haven't told us what _your problem_ with it is and what you have tried already.

Comment: @lanzz thanks mate, I've since edited the question

Comment: @user1038627 Good edit. I'm changing my vote to an upvote for you question. The %-symbols will trash the script since it's not correct Javascript syntax.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks mate, appreciate it. Again I apologise for the initial vagueness of the Q! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var rows = $(".row");
    rows.each(function(index, row) {
        var amount = parseFloat($(row).children(".amount").text());
        var gst = parseFloat($(row).children(".gst").text());
        var customTax = parseFloat($(row).children(".customTax ").text());
        var tax = (isNaN(gst) ? (!isNaN(customTax) ? customTax : 0) : gst);
        var totalSpan = $(row).children(".total");
        console.log("Amount: ", amount);
        console.log("Tax: ", tax);
        totalSpan.html("Total: " + (amount + amount * (isNaN(tax) ? 0 : tax) / 100).toFixed(2));
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<span id="row_1" class="row">
    <span class="amount">123.45</span>
    <span class="gst"></span> 
    <span class="customTax"></span> 
    <span class="total"><!-- # --></span>
</span>​
```

I have also posted this as a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FHMrW/1/

Note: I have replaced the `id`s with `class` attributes, to support multiple rows.

**EDIT: Included the code here, as per comment from  @t-j-crowder, and added `toFixed` on total.**

Comment: Always include the relevant code and explanation **in the answer itself**, don't just link. Just like with questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @Vidar S. Ramdal Wow, that's impressive. Thank you! Is it possible to limit the 'Total' to only two decimals?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thanks for the reminder, I have included the code in my answer

Comment: @user1038627 yes, by using `toFixed(2)`. I have updated the code.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Thanks again for this solution, I've deployed it and it's working. Although I have final question: can the output figure be formatted to include a comma for numbers in the thousands? ie. 35000 becomes 35,000

Answer (score 3):

> Can javascript calculate percentage?

Any language with math operators can calculate percentage. In your case, using your sample markup:

```
var baseAmount, taxRate, tax, total;

// Get the base amount, stripping off non-floating-point-number chars,
// convert to number
baseAmount = parseFloat($("#abc").text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/, ""));

// Same with the tax rate, divide by 100
taxRate = parseFloat($("#def").text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/, "")) / 100;

// Tax is baseAmount * taxRate
tax = baseAmount * taxRate;

// Add to base to get total
total = baseAmount + tax;
```

Now, you have to be careful of the limitations of IEEE-754 floating point numbers, which allow some imprecision in (`0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`, for instance), but if you do some `Math.round` stuff you should be mostly fine.